# Один градус тепла

Tags: употребление-слов

Понятно, что мороз начинается от нуля и ниже, а вот что с плюсовой температурой? Например, выражение "один градус тепла" — какое уж тут тепло-то?))
Заранее спасибо за ваши соображения.

Comment: Уж так устроен термометр, что разделяющий тепло и холод *ноль* соотнесён со свойствами воды — одного из важнейших для человека веществ. И фазовый переход воды "жидкость-лёд" нередко для него имеет принципиальное значение. Более важное, чем характеристика температурного для тела комфорта, обеспечивать который он давно научился в широком диапазоне природных условий.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, что  выражения  "градусы мороза" или "градусы тепла" характерны для разговорного стиля, в точных метеосводках  чаще  говорится  о градусах выше или ниже нуля. 
Один градус тепла или мороза вообще редко употребляется. В остальных случаях присутствует ОТНОСИТЕЛЬНАЯ оценка - с учетом того, как мы сегодня и сейчас воспринимаем  данный температурный режим.  Например, если стояли морозы 10-20 градусов, то 5 градусов ниже нуля морозом уже не кажется.

Comment: На улице -30, в юрте -10, в холодильнике +5))))

Answer (score 2):

Чистая условность. Выше нуля - тепло, ниже - холод. 
По Фаренгейту, например, тепло - до -18 гр. Цельсия...
Хотя в прошлом такое представление могло нести вполне конкретное значение. Дело даже не столько в образовании льда при 0 градусов, сколько в свойствах воды (льда) расширяться при отрицательных перепадах температур... Физику явления опускаю.